# page template for view

Tags: views, theming

I have a view which I want to give a different look and feel from the rest of my page. Now the view is displayed as a page at a specific URL. I have tried naming my custom page template like `views-view--mobile-special-events--page.tpl.php`, (`mobile-special-events` being the name of my View) but this didn't work, it seems to apply this template only to the actual view area on my page but I want to re-theme the complete page, what do I need?

**edit 1**

I found this page: https://www.drupal.org/node/701920 where they say that you can preparte a page template from the link but I called my template `page-mobile-special-events.tpl.php` while my page is reachable under `www.mysite.com/mobile-special-events` but it doesn't seem to work, I've cleared the cache... what's going on, I'm wondering... :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread you link to is for Drupal 6, if you are using Drupal 7 I think the template file should be:
`page--mobile-special-events.tpl.php` (note the double dash).